# How to parameterize prevent_destroy lifecycle configuration in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I have a variable defined locally, called `local.protect`, and defined in `variables.tf` with `default = true` and `type = bool`.  How do I get around the use of variables constraint on the `prevent_destroy` argument? I thought I could `local`.ize it (eg, `locals {protect = var.protect}`) but that doesn't work, either.

```
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 105, in resource "aws_eip" "backend_eip":
│  105:     prevent_destroy = local.protect
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsuitable value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 105, in resource "aws_eip" "backend_eip":
│  105:     prevent_destroy = local.protect
│ 
│ Unsuitable value: value must be known
```

In `main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_eip" "backend_eip" {
  vpc        = true
  depends_on = [module.vpc.igw_id]
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = local.protect # line 105
  }
}
```

In `variables.tf`:

```
variable "protect" {
  type = bool
  description = "Whether (true) or not (false) to protect EIP from deletion via `terraform destroy`."
  default = true
}
```

Use case here is being able to set this flag at runtime, for a set of resources (like five EIP), all at once.

Comment: You can't. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22544 the last comment here contains a workaround, but not a great one.

Comment: @jordanm boo.  should i delete this or you want to make it the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jordanm said,

> You can't. github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22544 the last comment here contains a workaround, but not a great one.

EDIT:

The not-great [workaround](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22544#issuecomment-543914039) in question is:

> As a workaround, since we use the S3 backend for managing our
> Terraform workspaces, I block the access to the Terraform workspace S3
> bucket for the Terraform IAM user in my shell script after Terraform
> has finished creating the prod resources. This effectively locks down
> the infrastructure in the workspace and requires a IAM policy change
> to re-enable it.

Comment: you should add the link of the comment here, the last comment has obviously now changed

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an alternative workaround that's might be more CI/CD friendly, since `prevent_destroy` can't be set to a variable.

The idea is to validate the terraform plan output and check if any resources were deleted or recreated.
It requires that the `apply`-stage will apply the saved plan of course, so that no unexpected change will be applied.

Either one can just grep the output the raw plan output for the messages below:

- Deletes in plan: `Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 4 to destroy.`
- No deletes in plan: `Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy`.

One can also output the plan in json and do the check of that output.
I.e.
`terraform plan ... -json > plan_output.json`

All in all, something like:

```
terraform plan -out plan_out.tfplan > tf_stdout.txt
cat tf_stdout.txt | grep ... # Fail on some condition
terraform apply plan_out.tfplan
```